# How to set an initial state for a Bidirectional LSTM Layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to set the initial state in an encoder which is composed of a Bidirectional `LSTM` Layer to 0's. However, if I input a single 0's matrix I get an error saying that a bidirectional layer has to be initialized with a list of tensors (makes sense). When I try to duplicate this 0's matrix into a list containing two of them (to initialize both `RNNs`), I get an error that the input shape is wrong. What am I missing here?

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, enc_units, batch_sz):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    self.batch_sz = batch_sz
    self.enc_units = enc_units
    self.embedding = keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.lstmb = keras.layers.Bidirectional(lstm(self.enc_units, dropout=0.1))

def call(self, x, hidden):
    x = self.embedding(x)
    output, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c = self.lstmb(x, initial_state=[hidden, hidden])
    return output, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c


def initialize_hidden_state(batch_sz, enc_units):
    return tf.zeros((batch_sz, enc_units))
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`. Received `state_spec`=[InputSpec(shape=(128, 512), ndim=2)]; however `cell.state_size` is [512, 512]
```

Note: the output of the function `initialize_hidden_state` is fed to the parameter `hidden` for the call function.

Answer (score 2):

Reading all of the comments and answers, I think I managed to create a working example.

But first some notes:

- I think the call to `self.lstmb` will only return all five states if, you specify it in the LSTM's constructor.
- I don't think you need to pass hidden state as a list of hidden states. You should just pass it as the initial state.

```py
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, enc_units, batch_sz):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.batch_sz = batch_sz
        self.enc_units = enc_units
        self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        # tell LSTM you want to get the states, and sequences returned
        self.lstmb = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(self.enc_units,
                                                                        return_sequences=True,
                                                                        return_state=True,
                                                                        dropout=0.1))

    def call(self, x, hidden):
        x = self.embedding(x)
        # no need to pass [hidden, hidden], just pass it as is
        output, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c = self.lstmb(x, initial_state=hidden)
        return output, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c


    def initialize_hidden_state(self):
        # I stole this idea from iamlcc, so the credit is not mine.
        return [tf.zeros((self.batch_sz, self.enc_units)) for i in range(4)]


encoder = Encoder(vocab_inp_size, embedding_dim, units, BATCH_SIZE)

# sample input
sample_hidden = encoder.initialize_hidden_state()
sample_output, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c = encoder(example_input_batch, sample_hidden)
print('Encoder output shape: (batch size, sequence length, units) {}'.format(sample_output.shape))
print('Encoder forward_h shape: (batch size, units) {}'.format(forward_h.shape))
print('Encoder forward_c shape: (batch size, units) {}'.format(forward_c.shape))
print('Encoder backward_h shape: (batch size, units) {}'.format(backward_h.shape))
print('Encoder backward_c shape: (batch size, units) {}'.format(backward_c.shape))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inputting a state size of `(batch_size, hidden_units)` and you should input a state with size `(hidden_units, hidden_units)`. Also it has to have 4 initial states: 2 for the 2 lstm states and 2 more becuase you have one forward and one backward pass due to the bidirectional.

Try and change this:

```
def initialize_hidden_state(batch_sz, enc_units):
    return tf.zeros((batch_sz, enc_units))
```

To

```
def initialize_hidden_state(enc_units, enc_units):
    init_state = [np.zeros((enc_units, enc_units)) for i in range(4)]
    return init_state
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm still getting an error even after this fix:
ValueError: An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`. Received `state_spec`=[InputSpec(shape=(512, 512), ndim=2)]; however `cell.state_size` is [512, 512]

Comment: I have edited the answer, try the change and see if it works

Comment: Still doesn't work, I get a different error now though:
ValueError: When passing `initial_state` to a Bidirectional RNN, the state should be a list containing the states of the underlying RNNs. Found: [<tf.Tensor 'zeros:0' shape=(512, 512) dtype=float32>]

Comment: Okey, then recover the first error and forget the edit. What about not inputting a tensor but an array? In the first error was complaining about this ` state_spec=[InputSpec(shape=(512, 512), ndim=2)]; `

Comment: Ok, so I propose the following. First, do not input an initial state. And then make the network return its state and see what shape it has. Like this: `keras.layers.Bidirectional(lstm(self.enc_units, dropout=0.1, return_state=True))`

Comment: It returns an output and 4 states: forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c.
All of them are of the shape (?,512)

Comment: There you have it, you should have a list of 4 states with shapes (512, 512) each one. Or at least this is what it seems. I have editted the question to cover this.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as well, I'm getting the following error:

if len(initial_state) != len(self.states):
TypeError: object of type 'Tensor' has no len()

Comment: Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not too late, I think your `initialize_hidden_state` function should be:

`def initialize_hidden_state(self):
    init_state = [tf.zeros((self.batch_sz, self.enc_units)) for i in range(4)]
    return init_state`

Comment: it still didn't work, i'm getting the exact same error as mentioned by OP

Answer (score 1):

@BCJuan has the right answer, but I had to make some changes to make it work:

```
def initialize_hidden_state(batch_sz, enc_units):
    init_state = [tf.zeros((batch_sz, enc_units)) for i in range(2)]
    return init_state
```

Very important: use `tf.zeros` not `np.zeros` since it is expecting a tf.tensor type.

If you are using a single LSTM layer in the Bidirectional wrapper, you need to return a **list** of 2 **tf.tensors** to init each RNN. One for the forward pass, and one for the backward pass.

Also, if you look at [an example in TF's documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention), they use `batch_sz` and `enc_units` to specify the size of the hidden state.

Comment: For Bidirectional LSTM you need two(cell state and the hidden state) for the forward and two for the backward. The total you need 4.
Two only for LSTM

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using the bidirectional wrapper, and just create 2 `LSTM` layers with one of them receiving the parameter `go_backwards=True` and concatenating the outputs, if it helps anyone.
I think the bidirectional Keras wrapper can't handle this sort of thing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I constructed my encoder with tf.keras.Model, and met the same error. this [PR](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9248) may help you.
Finally I built my model by tf.keras.layers.layer, and I'm still working on it. I'll update after I success!